# How should a narrative parenthetical remark be placed in reference to a dialog quotation?

Tags: editing, dialogue, narrative, quotes

I’m wondering how to place a narrative parenthetical remark in dialog. I’m proofreading a book with a quote that doesn’t look right to me:

He whispered, “I think she will have a child in Raspberry Moon (this was around July in early summer).”

The remark wasn’t said by the character, so it shouldn’t be in the quote, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the remark shouldn't be in the quote.

Comment: Not only should it not be in the quote, it shouldn't be written like that at all. That's a dreadful way to convey the current setting.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum The way it is written really excites me. I can well imagine a narrative style where these exact words would fit perfectly.

Comment: @what If this is a first-person narrative, with a casual tone, then yes, it would work. For a standard third-person omniscient or limited, no.

Answer (score 1):

If the narrator is making that comment, it should be outside the quote. Here are several iterative revisions:

He whispered, “I think she will have a child in Raspberry Moon." (This was around July in early summer).

He whispered, “I think she will have a child in Raspberry Moon." He said this around July in early summer.

Around July, in early summer, he whispered, “I think she will have a child in Raspberry Moon."

Answer (score 1):

A "Raspberry Moon" needs to be explained prior to the quote--probably as dialogue, but possibly as part of a third- person omniscient information dump. It is absolutely wrong to put parentheses within the quote. In newspapers and such, parenthetical remarks from the editor are placed in brackets [ ].

Although it would be amateur to do so, one could follow the quote with: *And Barney asked, "What's a Raspberry Moon?"*